# Decoding (and equating) special characters with the Django REST framework SearchFilter?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have implemented a Django Rest Framework SearchFilter in my backend, which for the most part works correctly. This is the code structure in **views.py**:

```
class JobsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Jobs.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['^name', '^job_type']
```

The only remaining problem is that when sending get requests with a special character, for example the Swedish letter å, Django doesn't recognize that å is the same letter as Å only in lower case (as it does with for example a and A). In the GET calls from the front end, å gets converted to %C3%A5 for lowercase and %C3%85 for uppercase.

This results in the search box not finding the jobs beginning with the letters *åäö* if the job title begins in uppercase (as in *Återvinning*). Does anyone know of a solution that makes the filter understand and equate uppercase and lowercase letters of special characters? Something along the lines of UTF-8 decoding?

I have looked for answers both in the [REST framework documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter) and here on Stack Overflow, without any luck.

New to Stack Overflow btw, I hope I'm doing the formatting correctly!

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: This was a while ago, but If I recall correctly, the problem was in fact mostly related to collation issues in the SQLite database. I think there is no solution other to change the database to something else with more character sets/collation support, unfortunately.